# Found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, json, swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var TextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var LableOfCity: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var LableOfTemp: UILabel!

@IBAction func getButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    getWeatherData("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(TextField.text)")
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getWeatherData("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func getWeatherData (urlString: String) {

    let url = NSURL (string: urlString)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error)  in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            self.setlLabels(data)

          })
        }
    task.resume()
}
func setlLabels(WeatherData: NSData) {
    var jsonError: NSError?

    let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(WeatherData, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as! NSDictionary

    if let name = json["name"] as? String {
     LableOfCity.text = name
    }
    if let main = json["main"] as? NSDictionary{
        if let temp = main["temp"] as? Double{
         LableOfTemp.text = String (format: "%.1f", temp)

        }
      }
    }
}
```

После запуска приложения возникает ошибка (на скриншоте). Не могу понять, как ее исправить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас на скриншоте есть все, что вам нужно: WeatherData пустая, jsonError - 3840, описание ошибки.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Как я уже написал: у вас WeatherData пустая, по этому при попытке сконвертировать ее в json происходит крэш. Вся информация в ошибке (NSCocoaErrorDomain, code - 3840)

- Как избавиться от ошибки?

Проверять, что в WeatherData что-то есть: например так `WeatherData.length > 0` перед тем, как ее преобразовывать в json

- Теперь ошибки нет, но погоду все равно не показывает, что делать?

вы скопировали пример не полностью, у вас:
`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London`

а должно быть:
`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=bd82977b86bf27fb59a04b61b657fb6f` - не хватает идентификатора приложения. Помните, что хотя этот линк и работает, вам надо будет заменить id в примере, на id своего приложения.